# VueUse OnClickOutside ignore options not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button, vueuse

i'm using `OnClickOutside` from `VueUse`, the vue code is:

```
<template>
  <button class="button" id="button1" ref="tempRef">AAA</button>
  <OnClickOutside id="clickOutside" :options="{ ignore: [tempRef] }" @trigger="console.log(tempRef)">
    <button class="button" id="button2">BBB</button>
  </OnClickOutside>
</template>

<script setup>
import { OnClickOutside } from '@vueuse/components'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const tempRef = ref()
</script>
```

So, my expectation is, when I click `button1`, the `OnClickOutside` won't be triggered since `tempRef` is inside the ignore.
But, it turns out, the console still output `tempRef` when I clicked `button1`. I've tried some adjustments but nothing works.
Do I misunderstand how to use ignore in `OnClickOutside`? How to fix this? Thx for the help

Here is the documentation for easy access: https://vueuse.org/core/onClickOutside/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refs are automatically unwrapped when used in the template, so instead of providing the ignore option a `ref` object, it's being provided the inner non-ref value.  If you provide an options object created in your `<script>` code it should work:

```
<template>
  <button id="button1" ref="tempRef" class="button">AAA</button>
  <OnClickOutside
    id="clickOutside"
    :options="options"
    @trigger="console.log(tempRef)"
  >
    <button id="button2" class="button">BBB</button>
  </OnClickOutside>
</template>

<script setup>
import { OnClickOutside } from '@vueuse/components'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const tempRef = ref()

const options = { ignore: [tempRef] }
</script>
```

The ignore option can also be given a selector string, so you could use that as an alternative if you want a template-only solution:

```html
<OnClickOutside
  id="clickOutside"
  :options="{ ignore: ['#button1'] }"
  @trigger="console.log(tempRef)"
>
```